# How is this question NARQ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A recent question asks, "[How do I find the cause for a huge difference in performance between two identical servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/454988)"

This appears to be getting shot down as "Not a Real Question" and I'm somewhat confused as to why:

- The question describes a real problem that the asker is experiencing.
- A good, canonical answer to this question surely could be valuable to future visitors.
- The question asks for general strategies -- what to look for and how -- and is not requesting product recommendations.

Why would this not be a real and appropriate question?

Comment: Looks kinda sorta polling to me. And will perhaps end up being too localized as well.

Comment: The OP posting a bounty on that question has merely postponed the inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

I won't put the final nail in it's coffin, but this seems like **Not A Real Question** or **Not Constructive** to me:

It is not an inherently ***BAD*** question, but as it stands it's effectively asking "Please troubleshoot this problem for me using your crystal ball" --  As it stands right now this question seems likely to devolve into an extended back-and-forth troubleshooting session, which may or may not ever lead to an answer, but will be so convoluted and confusing as to be virtually useless to someone trying to solve a similar problem in the future unless they're willing to wade through the entire chain of comments and discussion to get to the useful nugget at the end.

---

(Also on a personal note the asker is committing what I consider to be a mortal sin: The endless telescoping `Edit #:` at the end of a question.  We're ***NOT*** LiveJournal - Edits should be structured into the question so everything has context and makes sense to someone reading it for the first time.)